# Stylizing Material Checkbox - Display checkmark on hover

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I try to stylizing a Material Checkbox (https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview). There are several things that I have done without problems (like change color, border etc). I would like, but I can't seem to do it, only when the checkbox is unchecked, display the checkmark on hover. As the example on the right in the picture, this to indicate that we can click on the checkbox [checkbox-hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFDU6.png)

Any ideas ? Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you ask a question using this website please provide the code you have tried so far, so people can answer you quicker and easier. Please have a look at the tour on how to ask a proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkmark is hidden by setting the SVG path's `stroke-dashoffset` to ~23px.
In order for the checkmark to be shown on hover you'll want a CSS rule to set this value to 0px and supply a background colour to the checkbox so the checkmark can be seen.